# What is the probability that the marbles are the same color?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A bag has 4 red and 6 blue marbles. A marble is selected and not replaced, then a second is selected. What is the probability that both are the same color?

I thought it was the probability they have the same color is $\frac{4}{24}\cdot\frac{3}{23} + \frac{6}{24}\cdot\frac{5}{23} = \frac{7}{92}$.
But the system says it is wrong. can someone help me?

Comment: Where did the number $24$ come from?  How many marbles are in the bag in total?  What is the probability that when pulling a single marble out of the bag that the marble is red?

Comment: there are in total only $10$ marbles

Comment: The total number of balls is the sum of the red and blue, not the product.

Answer (score 3):

The solution in your answer is correct.  Here are two other methods.

**Method 1:**  The sample space consists of all selections of two of the ten marbles.  There are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways to select two of the ten marbles.

The favorable events are selecting two red marbles or two blue marbles.  The number of ways to select two of the four red marbles is $\binom{4}{2}$, and the number of ways to select two of the six blue marbles is $\binom{6}{2}$.  Hence, the probability to select two balls of the same color is
$$\Pr(\text{two marbles of the same color}) = \frac{\dbinom{4}{2} + \dbinom{6}{2}}{\dbinom{10}{2}}$$

**Method 2:**  Alternatively, the complementary event is selecting two marbles of different colors.  Subtracting the probability of this event from $1$ gives the probability of selecting  two marbles of the same color.  Since there are four ways to select a red marble and six ways to select a blue marble, the probability of selecting two marbles of different colors is
$$\Pr(\text{two marbles of different colors}) = \frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{6}{1}}{\dbinom{10}{2}}$$
Hence, the probability of selecting two marbles of the same color is
$$\Pr(\text{two marbles of the same color}) = 1 - \frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{6}{1}}{\dbinom{10}{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

I found that the probability that both marbles are red is given by:$$ P(\text{both red}) = P(\text{1st red}) \times P(\text{2nd red AFTER 1st red is drawn}). $$The probability that the first marble is red is $\frac{4}{10}$. After drawing a red marble, there are 3 red marbles and 9 marbles total left in the bag, so the probability that the second marble is also red is $\frac{3}{9}$. Therefore$$ P(\text{both red}) = \frac{4}{10}\times \frac{3}{9} = \frac{2}{15}. $$Similarly, the probability that both marbles are blue is given by:$$ P(\text{both blue}) = P(\text{1st blue}) \times P(\text{2nd blue AFTER 1st blue drawn}). $$The probability that that the first marble is blue is $\frac{6}{10}$. After drawing a blue marble, there are 5 blue marbles and 9 marbles total left in the bag, so the probability that the second marble is also blue is $\frac{5}{9}$. Therefore$$ P(\text{both blue}) = \frac{6}{10}\times \frac{5}{9} = \frac{1}{3}. $$Since drawing two red marbles and drawing two blue marbles are exclusive events, we add the individual probabilities to get the probability of one or the other occurring. Therefore:\begin{align*}P(\text{both same color}) &= P(\text{both red}) + P(\text{both blue}) \\ &= \frac{2}{15} + \frac{1}{3} = \boxed{ \frac{7}{15}}. \end{align*}